# how to check and pass variables if save button is clicked in a modal? javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

So i have a modal that pops up, it makes an ajax call and gives me 3 variables back to show. In the modal there is a save button and cancel button, if the save button is clicked i want to make another ajax call to save the variables in the database.

My problem is after the modal is open i cannot check if the save button is hit because then i can pass the variable. Maybe there is a way to pass the variables to the onclick so i can take it out of this function.

```
$(document).on("click", '.assignButton', function (event) {
    var assID = this.id;
    var tempNum = assID.substring(7);
    var dropdata = 'tempID=' + tempNum;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "showAssignInfo.php",
        data: dropdata,
        success: function (data) {
            var rowArray = data.split("%!");
            var teID = rowArray[0];
            var teName = rowArray[1];
            var coName = rowArray[2];
            $("#t1").html(teID);
            $("#t2").html(teName);
            $("#t3").html(coName);
        }
    });

    $('#assignModal').trigger('openModal');

    $(document).on("click", '.assignSave', function (event) {
        //Make ajax call with teID, teName, coName
        alert("save button is clicked.");
    });

});
```

Comment: You could have your variables defined at a higher scope so they are accessible in all click handlers. But then that's bordering on global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values using the `text()` method:

```
$("#t1").text();
$("#t2").text();
$("#t3").text();


$(document).on("click", '.assignSave', function(event)
{
    //Use these values in your ajax call
    $("#t1").text();
    $("#t2").text();
    $("#t3").text();

    alert("save button is clicked.");
});
```

Comment: the problem with this is that some of the html elements have ampersands.  so when i store it , it stores as Johnson #amp; Johnson

Comment: @bigdowg sorry it should be `$("#t1").text();`

Answer (score 0):

1.I am not sure that I understand you, but you can try it:

```
$(document).on("click", '.assignButton', function(event)
{
  var assID = this.id;
  var tempNum = assID.substring(7);
  var dropdata= 'tempID='+tempNum;
  var teID, teName, coName;

  $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: "showAssignInfo.php",
      data:dropdata,
      success: function(data) {

        var rowArray = data.split("%!"); 
        teID = rowArray[0];
        teName = rowArray[1];
        coName = rowArray[2];

        $("#t1").html(teID);
        $("#t2").html(teName);
        $("#t3").html(coName);                               
      }
  });
  $('#assignModal').trigger('openModal'); 

  $(document).on("click", '.assignSave', function(event)
  {
     //Here we can use teID, teName, coName
     alert("save button is clicked.");
  });

});
```

We moved that variables to the higher scope

2.In other way you need to trigger 'openModal' with extraParameters. You can read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-eventType-extraParameters).